# Wordpress won't generate image sizes for certain images

Tags: uploads, media-library, images

I have no idea why this particular image and others seem to be affected, but it's really annoying.

I have noticed, there is one image in particular that Wordpress just will not generate different images for.

I tested another image, and different sizes were created just fine. Went back to the original image, and even renamed it before uploading again, but still only the full size is uploaded and stored in the `uploads` folder.

As other images seem to work fine, I don't think it's a server misconfiguration. But I'm stuck as to what I can do to try and diagnose.

The image itself is a JPG, and has only words and hypens in the filename

`http://development.bellavou.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/lisa-wakeman-clinic-manager.jpg`

UPDATE:

As pointed out, I hadn't given any information on the image sizes, but the image being uploaded is way higher than any of the settings below. Is there anywhere to find more information on when images are uploaded? Does Wordpress have it's own logging section?

```
Full size image: 4752 × 3168
WP Thumbnail: 150 | 150 (crop)
WP Medium: 360 | 360
WP Large: 1280 | 1280
```

FURTHER UPDATE:

After looking at the error logs, I see this message: `development.bellavou.co.uk [Tue Feb 07 11:59:00 2017] [error] [client 81.137.229.53:47529] AH01215: Insufficient memory (case 4): /home/sites/bellavou.co.uk/public_html/development/wp-admin/async-upload.php`

But Googling this 'Insufficient memory' doesn't yield many results. Does anyone know what could be needed here? Any why it only affects some images?

Comment: it's annoying :( maybe there's an issue with attachment ID. why don't you try to regenerate thumbnails via plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Hi, thanks for that advice. I've actually done that several times, each time the plugin only detects one image size for this image, and so will not generate any other sizes.

Comment: Do you have SSH/ shell access to the server? If yes, you can use `php -m` to see the _modules_ that you have installed for PHP. If _Imagemagick_ or _Imagick_ is installed, then it is preferred over _GD_ and you can try to manually [downsize](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize) the image. If not, then _GD_ is in use and you want to consider installing the _Imagick_ extension for PHP (ask your hoster or on _Serverfault_). If that fails as well, then you will have to upgrade RAM on your server. Please [edit] the question with further progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress will only create image size if the original size is greater than the registered sizes.

That's just a hint as you didn't told us the image size and the register add_image_size() you add for your install.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated my question. I don't believe this is the case though.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing memory to 32GB and everything else did not work. Image sizes > 2106 Pixels werde not generated (Source is 60MP).

What worked was favouring the second choice image editor GD by adding:

```
add_filter('wp_image_editors', function($editors) {
    return ['WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick'];
});
```